# How can I convert a python array into a JSON string so that it can be stored in the database?

Tags: python, arrays, json, sqlite, pyramid

I know in javascript there is the stringify command, but is there something like this in python for pyramid applications? Right now I have a view callable that takes an uploaded stl file and parses it into a format as such. `data= [[[x1,x2,x3],...],[[v1,v2,v3],...]]` How can I convert this into a JSON string so that it can be stored in an SQLite database? Can I insert the javascript stringify command into my views.py file? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `json` module to do this:

```
 import json
 data_str = json.dumps(data)
```

There are other array representations that can be stored in a database as well (see `pickle`).

However, if you're actually constructing a database, you should know that's it's considered a violation of basic database principles (first normal form) to store multiple data in a single value in a relational database.  What you should do is decompose the array into rows (and possibly separate tables) and store a single value in each "cell".  That will allow you to query and analyze the data using SQL.

If you're not trying to build an actual database (if the array is completely opaque to your application and you'll never want to search, sort, aggregate, or report by the values inside the array) you don't need to worry so much about normal form but you may also find that you don't need the overhead of an SQL database.

Comment: the arrays I am storing are of variable length, so If I was to put each value in a different column, how do I know how many columns to put in

Comment: @BigBoy1337: For that, you use a 1-to-many relationship table, where there's one row for each array element. That's presumably why the answer says "into rows (**and possibly separate tables**)". (PS, great answer.)

Comment: If they are really sets of triplets, then you would use a table with three columns and add one row per triplet.  If the sub-arrays are also of variable length there are a variety of design strategies you can use.

Comment: well the entire array is basically a tuple where the first item and second items are both arrays of triplets

Comment: Does the array model anything in the real world?  If so, and you want access to the parts as part of your storage mechanism, you should model that thing (or things) in the database, and convert the data structure to that model for storage.

Comment: yeah it models an object described with stl file format. The first tuple consists of all cartesian points on the object and the second tuple defines triangles by the ordering these vertices

Comment: Can you explain more about how to model it in the database? Does this involve looking into a 1 to many relationship table?

Comment: A quick look at the Wikipedia page for STL suggests that the files have a regular format, you could put that format into one (or maybe more) tables.  However, I'm thinking this may actually be one of those cases in which you *won't* want access to the component parts of the structure from SQL -- do you need to find all the shapes that  have vertices within a certain area, or anything like that?  What's the advantage to using an SQL database over the file system for storage?

Comment: However, if the STL data is one opaque datum associated with other meaningful information that is appropriate for SQL storage, then your original design is fine.

Comment: well I'm not doing anything with the stl data, in fact on the rendering template I call it in the same exact format that It is originally created in. The only trouble is that I need a way to store it and I was assuming that converting it to store in a database and the converting it back to render in a template was the easiest way to do that

Answer (score 1):

you also can use [cjson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-cjson), it is faster than `json` library.

```
import cjson
json_str = cjson.encode(your_string)
```